# Getting ERROR "You must provide at least one recurring price in `subscription` mode when using prices."

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Hello I am beginner in Django while trying to create Subscription with stripe i am getting error as

`InvalidRequestError at /stripe/create-checkout-session Request req_M2eko0H9LwXvDz: You must provide at least one recurring price in` subscription `mode when using prices.`

This is my views.py code snippet.

`checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('main:complete') ) + "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('main:cancelled_transaction')),
client_reference_id=request.user.id if request.user.is_authenticated else None,
customer_email = email,
payment_method_types=['card'],

```
        line_items=[
            {
                'quantity': 1,
                'price_data':{
                    'product':'PRODUCT_ID',
                    'unit_amount':settings.STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
                    'currency':'INR',
                    # 'recurring':'DAY'
                }
            }
        ],
        mode='subscription',
    )        `
```

I have tried to use https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-recurring in my code.

Answer (score 2):

This could also happen if the subscription product that you're using isn't configured correctly. In my case, I was using the type "user decides what to pay" instead of the standard pricing, which in fact has the "recurring" configuration needed, as pointed out by orakaro.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't specify the [recurring](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=cli#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-recurring) parameter to declare this is a recurring price, as the error says. Note that you can view your request in Stripe Dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/logs/req_M2eko0H9LwXvDz